# Assign value to variable only if is not null - Kotlin

Tags: null, kotlin, operators

Is there a clean way in Kotlin to assign a value to a variable only if the value is not null?

My example is:

```
if(x != null)
   y = x
```

I found a solution like

```
y = x? : return
```

but I don't understand if this does what I want and how this operator works.

Comment: If you need to set property it'possible redefine default setter, for example 
`var y: Int? = 0
  set(x: Int?) {
     if (x != null)
        field = x
  }`

Comment: @user8320224 problem with that solution is `y` is probably a non-null field, hence the nullability check before assignment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The operator is called Elvis Operator. It evaluates if `x` is not null and if that's true, assigns `x` to `y`. If it is null, it evaluates the statement after the question mark, returning immediately and therefore leaving `y` untouched.

Comment: Sorry, the solution was "y = x ?: return" , not x = y ?: return. This solution worked for me "y = x? : return". Now I understand the Elvis operator thanks to your description. Can you correct your answer for the correct solution?... My mistake.

Comment: This will work in some scenarios, but with the question worded as is, this will not always be an appropriate solution. It also returns from the current function if x is null, so it does more than just only assigning x to y if x is not not null. If there was more code in the function after this line, that code would be skipped if x was null since the function already returned.

Comment: Why is iit called the Elvis operator?

Comment: Just watch a video of Elvis dance. Seriously. That is the reason.

Comment: @Kramer - because, if you look at the ?: sideways, it's supposed to look like the signature hairstyle of Elvis Presley.

Answer (score 65):

Another solution if You don't want to return from function just yet:

```
x?.let{ y = it }
```

Which checks if `x` is non-null then passes it as the only parameter to the lambda block.

This is also a safe call in case your `x` is a `var`.

Comment: This seems to be the kotlin way.  But i think my answer is easier to read (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65930287/624814).

Answer (score 11):

For those searching and want a solution that does **not** immediately return.  You can hold your nose and do this:

`y = x ?: y`

As a good programmer I shudder to assign a variable to itself just to satisfy syntax.  But that's kotlin for you!  Those designers thought of everything!

Comment: That the simple and cleanest way to do it I found to. If you find another way to do it I would like to know it.

Comment: It's acceptable for local variables but I would stay away from it when `y` is a property: if it has custom getter or setter those will be invoked while reassigning to itself.

Comment: @Pawel  Yes, that's yet another reason to hold your nose while doing this.  So many hidden potential side effects in kotlin.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is the exact same but with less writing as:

```
if(x != null)
    y = x
else
    return
```

When using the Elvis Operator it shortens the if else statement to:

```
y=x ?: return
```

If the left side is true (x is not null) then y will be assigned, else the right side will be executed.